# Google BigQuery SQL issue with combining regular functions with WINDOW functions

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm looking at a table of orders for an ecommerce website and trying to build a customers table with some basic info about each customer.

I'm getting caught up when trying to use WINDOW functions like NTH_VALUE in combination with normal functions.

The orders table looks like this:

```
order_id | customer_id | order_date | revenue
----------------------------------------------
    1    |      11     | 2017-01-01 |  5.0
    2    |      11     | 2018-02-01 |  2.25
    3    |      12     | 2019-03-01 |  1.0
    4    |      13     | 2016-04-01 |  12.0
    5    |      13     | 2016-05-01 |  15.25
    6    |      13     | 2018-06-01 |  25.25
```

I'm looking to build a Customers table that looks like this:

```
customer_id | num_orders | first_order_date | first_order_revenue | second_order_date
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      11    |     2      |    2017-01-01    |        5.0          |    2018-02-01
      12    |     1      |    2019-03-01    |        1.0          |        n/a
      13    |     3      |    2016-04-01    |        12.0         |    2018-06-01
```

My code should be something like this:

```
SELECT
customer_id,
COUNT(customer_id) num_orders,
MIN(order_date) first_order_date,
FIRST_VALUE(revenue) OVER w1 first_order_revenue,
NTH_VALUE(order_date, 2) OVER w1 second_order_date

FROM `orders`
GROUP BY customer_id
WINDOW w1 as (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY order_date ASC)
```

But it's telling me I need to GROUP "revenue" and "order_date" via errors like this:

"SELECT list expression references column revenue which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [5:13]"

But when I do that, it returns a row for every order where first_order_date is different for each, first_order_revenue is the same (correct) value for each, and the second_order_date is correct except for the first row...where it is null:

```
customer_id | num_orders | first_order_date | first_order_revenue | second_order_date
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      13    |      1     |    2016-04-01    |        12.0         |       *null*
      13    |      1     |    2016-05-01    |        12.0         |     2016-05-01
      13    |      1     |    2018-06-01    |        12.0         |     2016-05-01
```

I'm slowly teaching myself SQL but this specific issue I can't find any solutions for online. I'm guessing it might take a nested SELECT statement for the WINDOW functions that is then JOINed with the non-WINDOW functions? Something like that? I've tried a few different solutions but nothing is working so far.

Thank you for anyone that can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a subquery and conditional aggregation might be simpler:

```
SELECT customer_id, COUNT(*) num_orders,
       MIN(order_date) first_order_date,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN revenue END) as revenue_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 2 THEN revenue END) as revenue_2
FROM (SELECT o.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY order_date) as seqnum
      FROM `orders` o
     ) o
GROUP BY customer_id;
```

Or, put the values in an array:

```
SELECT customer_id, COUNT(*) num_orders,
       MIN(order_date) first_order_date,
       ARRAY_AGG(revenue ORDER BY order_date LIMIT 2) as revenue_1_2
FROM `orders` o
GROUP BY customer_id;
```

Comment: Ah interesting.Using the ROW_NUMBER() to create the 'seqnum' column and then you can pull whatever column you want if it matches the seqnum you want.

Comment: Woops it sent too soon. Was going to add:

The use of MAX is just a kind of workaround for pulling those values without having to GROUP them, correct?

Comment: @LeeLK . . . Yes.  The `MAX()` is pulling one value per `seqnum` and there is only one value.